# Eclipse Kepler (4.3) JUnit (3.81) view not showing test results, using code created by maven-archetype-quickstart

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, junit

Getting back into Java coding after being away for a while, downloaded the latest Maven (3.1.1), the latest Eclipse (Kepler), the latest JDK (1.7.0_45), created a new Maven project in Eclipse (using the quickstart archetype, which looks like it defaulted to JUnit 3.8.1), opened `AppTest.java`, selected "Run As JUnit Test" (not JUnit Plug-in Test), and **nothing shows up in the JUnit view**.

Shouldn't it at least say something like "Runs: 1/1"?  If I change the code in testApp() to "`assertTrue( false)`", then I don't see a failure (although if I debug, sure enough, an exception gets thrown).  If I put a `println()` in the test, I see its output in the console view.  If I run `mvn test` from the command line, I get a lovely stacktrace and the word "FAILURE!" (and my `println()` output).

So.  Something basic is wrong somewhere, but what?

Comment: I have seen a lag there (i.e. the tests were completed before the view would start to show them) but never nothing :-/ Did you try to run the tests with a JUnit 4 runner? Maybe JUnit 3.x is broken :-/

Comment: Yeah, just tried it w/JUnit 4.11.  (Didn't change the tests, though.  Do I need to annotate them?)  Maven downloaded some new stuff and runs the tests just fine.  The JUnit view in Eclipse shows that it's running the tests, but it doesn't show results.

Comment: I migrated a workspace from Eclipse INDIGO and I have the same problem here.. (Kepler SR1 + JUnit 4.11)

Comment: Good to know I'm not alone.

Comment: The same happened to me.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you checked the "Show Failures Only" option? (on the same bar as "Rerun Test"). It happened to me :)

I think I repeat your problem. It happens when the JUnit window is opened initially in eclipse (for example I detached the view as separate window and it shows when eclipse starts).
With fresh start (window/view shown) I run tests and don't see anything in it, when I close it and run unit tests (via 'run as') window reopens but now results are shown.

Comment: I pressed the rerun test button. Thanks for the hint.